# Real-Time Synchronization Issue in Microsoft Teams Tab App - Issue with Live Share SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, synchronization, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm working on a Microsoft Teams Tab App using the 'Teams Toolkit' extension in Visual Studio Code. The app functions as a questionnaire that allows the meeting organizer to share questions, answer options, and a timer with meeting attendees, presenters, and organizers. However, I'm encountering challenges with real-time content synchronization, and I need help in resolving this issue.

Here are the key details:

- I have configured the app manifest as per the guidelines provided in the Microsoft Docs.
- I'm using JavaScript and React for my application.
- I've attempted to implement synchronization using the @microsoft/live-share SDK, and I'm using LiveState to track the current question index.
- The app retrieves an array of objects from an API, where each object contains a question, four options, a unique 2-digit ID, and the correct answer.
- The issue is that when the organizer or presenter shares the application, participants receive the questions and timer on their devices, but the content is not synchronized in real-time. Changes made by the organizer or presenter are not reflected simultaneously for other participants.

Here's what I've tried:

- Using the @microsoft/live-share SDK and LiveState for tracking the current question index.
- Ensuring that my API fetches the latest data correctly.

My specific question is:
How can I achieve effective real-time synchronization of content and the timer in my Microsoft Teams Tab App across all meeting attendees, presenters, and organizers? Are there specific techniques, tools, or approaches that I should consider to ensure that all participants view the same content at the same time?

If you have any insights, suggestions, code examples, or resources that could help me address this synchronization challenge, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you!

Comment: it seems like you're on the right track by using the @microsoft/live-share SDK for real-time collaboration. However, to ensure that all participants view the same content at the same time, you need to make sure that the state of your app is shared across all users. This is where the LiveState comes into play.LiveState is a real-time, multi-user state that you can use to store and share data across all users. When you update the LiveState, all connected clients are notified of the change and can react accordingly.

Comment: For more information on how to use the LiveShare SDK, you can refer-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-live-share-quick-start

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I understand your explanation. In my situation, I've granted the meeting organizer and presenters the rights to display and modify questions. However, I don't want other attendees to receive notifications when changes are made. I simply want the question content and timer to update as the organizer or presenter makes adjustments, without notifying or ask attendees to refresh it on their side.